# Why does spark-submit throw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: '-Dspark/tachyonStore/folderName=...' on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am using Spark 1.1.1 with Hadoop 2.4.0, both installed on Windows.

When submitting a job using `spark-submit` in `yarn-client` mode, as follows:

```
bin\spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn-client lib\spark-examples-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar 5
```

I am getting the following error:

```
14/12/12 11:18:35 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:

     appMasterRpcPort: -1
     appStartTime: 1418411892899
     yarnAppState: FAILED

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application already ended,might be killed or not able to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApp(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:93)
```

Examining the yarn logs, I can see the following error:

```
Log Contents:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: '-Dspark/tachyonStore/folderName=spark-3cb0e049788b-487f-8f5d-3d52c6ad209b'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '-Dspark.tachyonStore.folderName=sark-3cb0e049-788b-487f-8f5d-3d52c6ad209b'
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: '-Dspark.tachyonStore.folderName=spark-3cb0e049-88b-487f-8f5d-3d52c6ad209b'.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Upon examining the command itself,

```
14/12/11 12:34:51 INFO Client:   command: %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -server -Xmx512m 
-Djava.io.tmpdir=%PWD%/tmp '-Dspark.tachyonStore.folderName=spark-3cb0e049-788b-
487f-8f5d-3d52c6ad209b' '-Dspark.yarn.secondary.jars=' '-Dspark.driver.host=dev1
-win-vm' '-Dspark.driver.appUIHistoryAddress=' '-Dspark.app.name=Spark Pi' '-Dsp
ark.driver.appUIAddress=dev1-win-vm:4040' '-Dspark.jars=file:/C:/deploy/spark-1.
1.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-examples-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar' '-Dspark.fileserver.
uri=http://192.168.53.94:53420' '-Dspark.master=yarn-client' '-Dspark.driver.por
t=53416' org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher --class 'notused' --jar
null  --arg  'dev1-win-vm:53416' --executor-memory 1024 --executor-cores 1 --num
-executors  2 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
```

I suspect if the quoting of the -D flags is done with double quotes instead of single quotes, the command should work.

Anybody knows how to resolve this issue?   I am wondering if there is some setting to control this.